# styled-components defaultProps

Tags: typescript, styled-components

If I have the following button with a defaultProp

```
export interface IButton {
  variant: 'action' | 'secondary';
}

export const Button = styled('button')<IButton>`
  background-color: #fff;

  ${props =>
    props.variant === 'action' &&
    css`
      color: blue;
    `};

  ${props =>
    props.variant === 'secondary' &&
    css`
      color: gray;
    `};
`;

Button.defaultProps = {
  variant: 'action',
};
```

Is there a way to type it? When trying to use it like

```
<Button>Hello</Button>
```

Typescript complains about not passing variant, is there a way to type defaultProps with styled components?

Comment: This question is outdated. This now works with StyledComponents + TypeScript + React. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript 3.0's support for `defaultProps` in checking JSX elements requires the type of the `defaultProps` to be declared on the component.  Mutating the `defaultProps` of an existing component won't work, and I'm not aware of any good way to declare the `defaultProps` on a component generated by a function like `styled`.  (In a way, this makes sense: the library creates a component and doesn't expect you to modify it.  Maybe the library even sets `defaultProps` itself for some internal purpose.)  kingdaro's solution is fine, or you can use a wrapper component:

```
const Button1 = styled('button')<IButton>`
  background-color: #fff;

  ${props =>
    props.variant === 'action' &&
    css`
      color: blue;
    `};

  ${props =>
    props.variant === 'secondary' &&
    css`
      color: gray;
    `};
`;

export class Button extends React.Component<IButton> {
  static defaultProps = {
    variant: 'action'
  };
  render() {
    return <Button1 {...this.props}/>;
  }
}
```

Comment: If I go with approach TS complains that `onClick` does not exist on type intrinsicattributes. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add all the relevant code to the question and I'll take a look.  (I don't see a use of `onClick`.)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you want by destructuring your props.

It seems that you still have to let your component know about its prop types. For that, just pass all props without destructuring them (see background-color down below).

```
import styled from "styled-components";

interface IProps {
  variant?: 'action' | 'secondary';
}

export const Button = styled.div`
  ${(props: IProps) => `background-color: #fff;`}
  ${({ variant = 'action' }) => variant === 'action' ? `color: blue;` : `color: gray;`}
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, this isn't quite possible yet, and unfortunately isn't covered by the `defaultProps` support added in TS 3.0 (that only applies to normal component classes, and *I think* functional components). Others feel free to correct me if I'm wrong on this.

There are other ways to write it, though. Here's how I usually go about doing it:

```
export interface IButton {
  variant?: 'action' | 'secondary';
}

const variantStyles = {
  action: css`
    color: blue;
  `,
  secondary: css`
    color: gray;
  `,
};

export const Button = styled('button')<IButton>`
  background-color: #fff;
  ${props => variantStyles[props.variant || 'action']};
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Dec 2022, the example code in the original question works for me using Styled Components in React.

---

I found this question when searching for a way to specify a default StyleComponents theme. This is how I did it:

```
interface ITheme {
  color: string;
}

const defaultTheme: ITheme = {
  color: 'blue';
}

interface IButton {
  theme?: Theme;
}

export const Button = styled('button')<IButton>`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color};
`;

Prose.defaultProps = {
  theme: defaultTheme,
};
```

Using the above example I can use the button with and without a StyledComponents `ThemeProvider`.

With `ThemeProvider`:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={{ color: 'red' }}>
  <Button>I am a red button</Button>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Without `ThemeProvider`:

```
<Button>I am a blue button</Button>
```

There is an example of this -- though not in TypeScript -- in the Advanced docs's "Theming" code example: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming

---

Also -- unless the example is contrived to use `defaultProps` -- there is a simpler way to have a default color in the question's example without using `defaultProps`:

```
export interface IButton {
  variant: 'action' | 'secondary';
}

export const Button = styled('button')<IButton>`
  background-color: #fff;
  color: ${({ variant }) => (variant === 'secondary') ? 'gray' : 'blue' };
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

For most cases I use a wrapper component with default values:

```
interface IProps {
    // not optional
    variant: 'action' | 'secondary';
}

const SButton = styled.button<IProps>`
    ...styles
`

// make optional
export const Divider = (props: Partial<IProps>) => {
    // set default value
    const { variant = 'action', ...rest } = props;

    // insert default value
    return <SButton variant={variant} {...rest}>{children}</SButton>;
};
```

> Also better to separate styled props and main component props

```
interface IProps extends Partial<IStyledProps> {
    // component props
}

// or if you have composed component with multiple styled components
interface IProps extends Partial<IStyledProps1>, Partial<IStyledProps2>, Partial<IStyledProps3> {
    // component props
}
```